# Apple Map Kit and 3D Model

Tags: google-maps, opengl-es, 3d, mapkit

On Map Kit (Apple or Google), it’s possible to add a custom annotation with our own image in the map. In the same time, we can have a 3D view by showing building, but the custom annotation will still be showing a 2D image.

My questions :

Is it possible to add a 3D Model in the map and how ?
How would you use openGL inside the map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that yet. Apple just opened up the API for 3D manipulation of the map view, so I would expect it in a possible future release.

Comment: Too bad to hear that. Let's expect Apple release more possibilities with his new version. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @incanus is this possible yet? Adding a 3d object to the map. I'm guessing no, i've looked everywhere and don't know if i'm just missing it.